# How can I plot this diagram in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please help me. How can [image]I draw this using tikzpicture. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: By the way, you should have a look at the `circuitikz` [package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf). There are some questions on this site about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14152]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains, 
                decorations.markings,
                positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm,
  start chain = going below,
            > = {Stealth[scale=0.8]},
     C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.2em, on chain},
   ->-/.style = {decoration={markings, mark=at position .25 with {\arrow{>}}},
                 ->, postaction={decorate}}
                    ]
\node (x1) [C]  {$x_1$};
\node (x2) [C]  {$x_2$};
\node (x3) [C]  {$x_3$};
    \node [on chain]    {$\vdots$};
\node (xn) [C]  {$x_n$};
%
\draw[->-]  (x1) -- ++ (3,0);
\draw[->-]  (x2) -- ++ (3,0);
\draw[->-]  (x3) -- ++ (3,0);
\draw[->-]  (xn) -- ++ (3,0);
%
\coordinate[right=12mm of x1]   (xr1);
\coordinate[right=14mm of x2]   (xr2);
\coordinate[right=16mm of x3]   (xr3);
\coordinate[right=18mm of xn]   (xrn);
\coordinate[above left=12mm of x1]   (xl1);
\coordinate[above left=14mm of x1]   (xl2);
\coordinate[above left=16mm of x1]   (xl3);
\coordinate[above left=18mm of x1]   (xln);
%
\draw[->] (xr1) |- (xl1) |- (xn.160);
\draw[->] (xr2) |- (xl2) |- (xn);
\draw[->] (xr3) |- (xl3) |- (xn.200);
\draw[->] (xrn) |- (xln) |- (x3.200);

\draw[->]   (xl1 |- x2.160) -- (x2.160);
\draw[->]   (xl1 |- x3) -- (x3);
\draw[->]   (xl2 |- x1.160) -- (x1.160);
\draw[->]   (xl2 |- x3.160) -- (x3.160);
\draw[->]   (xl3 |- x1) -- (x1);
\draw[->]   (xl3 |- x2) -- (x2);
\draw[->]   (xln |- x1.210) -- (x1.210);
\draw[->]   (xln |- x2.210) -- (x2.210);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Above MWE  can be by use of loops much shorter.

Comment: Thank you so much, I want to add three dots between the last two circles. Can you do this?

Comment: @shivshankar, of course I can, but this you should try yourself ...

Comment: done,  by using \path (x3) -- node[auto=false]{\vdots} (xn);.

Comment: @shivshankar, I'm glad that you managed yourself to add vertical dots. Now I add to answer an alternative solution for those dots.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @shivshankar, you are welcome!